# UICollectionViewCell constraint error after reloadData

Tags: swift, uikit, autolayout

This is my custom UICollectionViewCell code. I am only giving a constraints for the subviews in the configureViews() function.

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  private lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = PaddingLabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline).pointSize)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    let widthConstant = floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) / 3)
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant).isActive = true
    return label
  }()

  private lazy var bottomLine = UIView()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureViews()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    configureViews()
  }

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    nameLabel.text = nil
  }
}

private extension CategoryCell {
  func configureViews() {
    contentView.addSameSizeConstrained(subView: nameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(bottomLine)

    bottomLine.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      bottomLine.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      bottomLine.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
      bottomLine.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
      bottomLine.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: AppLayoutGuidance.spacingHalf / 4),
    ])
  }
}
```

When the cell is first rendered, there is no problem, but when I call the collectionView.reloadData() function, a constraint error appears on the console. Do you have any idea?

Edit: Constraint Console Log

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000d01090 App.PaddingLabel:0x13d494320.width == 130   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000d010e0 H:|-(0)-[App.PaddingLabel:0x13d494320]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x13d467360 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000d01130 App.PaddingLabel:0x13d494320.trailing == UIView:0x13d467360.trailing   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000d02850 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x13d467360.width == 0   (active)>"
```

Comment: Can you show the cell in its entirety?

Comment: I'm sorry, and can you share the error or warning message in the debugger console? This is such a simple cell, why even use a stack view? Just add the label and the line to the cell's content view using constraints. You can simplify this cell down to something so basic that it's virtually future proof.

Comment: Yes you're right this is simple cell but at the beginning I was planning to add other subviews. I edited my question according to your comment, is that what you wanted to say? By the way, this is still produces a constraint error when the reloadData function triggered. There is no problem in the first rendering.

Comment: And what's the error or warning message in the console?

Comment: I added the console warning to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the addSameSizeConstrained function, as the name suggests, makes the frames of the view added with the contentview the same.So the `width` of the `nameLabel` is equal to the `contentView`.

But when defining the `label`, you gave the label a width value of `floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) / 3)`

`UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x13d467360.width == 0` this message is basically give us that information. You have to give `priority` one of the constraint , these are :

> - nameLabel width constraint in declaration = `floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) / 3)`
> - nameLabel width constraint in equaled contentView width in `addSameSizeConstrained`

You can fix this by giving priority to one of the constraints:

```
let widthConstant = floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) / 3)
let const = label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant)
   const.priority = .defaultLow
   const.isActive = true
return label
```

You are not getting this warning in console for first time load  because your collectinview's estimated size must be `Automatic`. If you change with `None` , you will see this warning when you load for the first time.